# Using JQuery to unselect choices

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

How do I use JQuery to unselect a choice field?

I'm currently trying to unselect some checkboxes if a previous choice is changed.

For example:

Choice1 is Yes / No. With a dropdown selection.
If Yes is selected, Choice2 will show.

Choice2 is Red / Blue / Green. With checkboxes, so people can select multiple.

If I change the choice1 to No, Choice2 is set to disappear.
But the choices are still selected behind the scenes.

How do I make it so that when I change Choice1 to No, it'll also unselect all the colours chosen in Choice2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , Here what need to be done is on the first choice **.Change** function before making it visible or hidden you need to make the Second Choice options unchecked. this can be achieved as given below:

```
$('#firstChoiceID').change(function()
{
  if($('#firstChoiceID option:selected').text() == "No")
{
//this will make all the check boxes in the page unchecked
$('input[type="Checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
//This you can use to uncheck the specific checkbox using its id
$('#chkRequestnota').prop("checked", false);
}

});
```